# Ubuntu 13.4 starts super-slow (90 seconds) on a 2x 2GHz / 4GB Ram laptop

Tags: boot, performance

Ubuntu needs 90 seconds to start, Windows 7 only needs 45 seconds. Here is the generated bootchart: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItVmO.png). I hope you can tell me where it wastes it's time. Laptop specifications:

2x 2GHz, 4 GB Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "fixed" after reinstalling Ubuntu (I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 now). It might've been caused because my PC was upgraded all the way up from Ubuntu 10.4 to 13.4, and many many unneeded software polluted the start process.

Answer (score 2):

well, the chart is pretty self explanatory, as expected in any configuration the usual bottleneck is the HDD or any other I/O peripheral, especially on notebook machines, that chart is almost all pink and the pink part is almost always hitting the roof.
You probably have a slow 5400 rpm HDD with an really high seek time.

Your CPU it's also a low end one but this doesn't really matter.

Comment: Hmm. Does that explain why Windows only needs 45 seconds on the same laptop?

Comment: @Christian this means nothing, compare 2 different OS will lead you to nowhere. Microsoft also can benefit from BIOS-related and power-related patented technology from the OEM vendors that can provide a significant, on the other hand you shouldn't forget that the "standard" kernel available on Ubuntu it's compiled with a lot of features so you can run Ubuntu on a lot of different machines.

Comment: Ok thank you. I didn't notice that my disk's chart is hitting the roof the whole time.